# Rename Add to Cart to Buy Now on WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I'm trying to rename the WooCommerce **Add to Cart button** to **Buy Now**. But I have tried using the below code on functions.php

**// To change add to cart text on single product page**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text',
 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );

function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Add To Bag', 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```

**// To change add to cart text on product archives(Collection) page**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text',
 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );

function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
   return __( 'Add To Bag', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Sadly, the code doesn't change the text. This has not been a problem for me with other e-commerce websites. This website is using the Eduma Theme and have designed for a learning portal. So, I tried all the possible solutions and nothing works. Even trying to change it through a plugin fails.

Appreciate if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in correct way for `Woocommerce` site!

If you think the **Add to Cart button** is for `Woocommerce`, just add a **priority** to `add_filter`. Because your theme or one of the plugin, may apply another filter after your filter. You need to make sure your filter has a higher priority. see example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text',
'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text', 9999);

function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Add To Bag', 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```

But i think the button is for `LearnPress` because of using `Eduma` Theme. try this:

```
add_filter( 'learn-press/purchase-course-button-text', 
'learnpress_custom_add_to_cart_text', 99);

function learnpress_custom_add_to_cart_text() {
     return 'Buy Now';
}
```